# Selectors in Redux - What does it mean for a React Component to know about redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, selector

Selectors are (among other reasons) used to hide state from components. Is this statement correct?

Say I have **2 reducers**:

**currentUser:**

```
{ 
  currentUserId: 'abc'
}
```

**allUsers**

```
{ 
  byId: {
  {
   abc: {
         name: "John"
         age: 21
        }
   def: {
         name: "Dave"
         age: 51
        }
   ghi: {
         name: "Gunners"
         age: 98
        }
  }
},
  allIds : ['abc','def','ghi'] //this is a list; users have a certain order, that is preserved here
}
```

**Say I now want to get some derived state. I will use a selector so that my component does not have to deal with the reducers state directly.** This (apart from memoization/performance) is part of the rationale behind selectors, correct? So I implement a selector that returns a user to my `mapStateToProps` function.

**But:** now my component still has to know about how the user object looks like? E.g. that there is `obj.name` and `obj.age` - so how and where does **knowing about state** begin and where does it end? Or, alternatively, and a bit more likely I presume, what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: A selector eg getUser returns the user from the state no matter what the store looks like. So the component knows that getUser returns a user but not how it is saved with redux. The component only knows about the selectors not the state. There is the cut.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused about your question. Can't comment...
It's a good idea to use selectors because it can make the code more manageable, or you just need something more specific from the state.

For instance, if you have a notification reducer that contains both read and unread notifications you could create a selector that will handle removing the read notifications so you can only display the unread notifications.

So mapStateToProps will push anything that is given to it. Whatever is returned from your selector will be pushed into the props of the component.

If you wanted it to only know about name and age you can really easily do this without creating a separate selector.

```js
// taking into consideration the code you posted

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    users: state.allUsers.byId
})
```

now mapStateToProps will only know about name and age.